# How to render a block in custom jade filter?

Tags: node.js, pug

I have two jade templates:

```
# base_template
block do_something
    :custom_filter
        block do_something_main
```

and

```
extends base_template

block do_something_main
    h1 Hello There!
```

I have defined the custom filter as follows:

```
var jade = require("jade");
jade.filters.custom_filter = function(html, options) {
    var output = jade.render(html, {filename: options.filename});
    // modify the output
    return "<h1>AWESOME RACCOONS!</h1>" + output;
}
```

However, the call to `jade.render(...)` fails to render the `do_something_main` block. Everything works fine if I do not define another block inside my custom filter.

Eg, making the base_template not define the do_something_main block will render content correctly, but it's not the behavior nor inheritance pattern that I want:

```
# base_template
block do_something
    :custom_filter
        .awesome_class HELLO THERE
```

How do I get `jade.render(...)` to render a block inside a custom filter?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and I think is not possible to do it in a clean way with the current version of Jade.

In the parser source code: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/lib/compiler.js#L488 the contents of the filter is passed to the filter function untouched.

However it's possible to hack Jade to do it, but there is no gurantee that it will to work on future versions:

- Jade exposes some variables to the compiled mixin code, like `buf`, `block`, and any additional data that you pass to Jade.
- `block` is a function that renders the contained block. Sadly that function doesn't return any value because it affects the buffer directly.

Based in these findings, I was able to create a hacky workaround:

```
mixin example()
  - var prevBuf = buf;
  - buf = []
  - block()
  - var blockResult = buf.join('');
  - buf = prevBuf;
  = myFilter(blockResult)

div
  +example()
    | **Hello** world!
```

In order to make it work you need to pass `myFilter` function to Jade compilation.
If you run Jade manually, pass that info to `jade.render`:

```
jade.render(src, {myFilter: function (txt) {...}});
```

If you run Jade with grunt, pass it into the data option (see https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jade#data). Passing it in `filters` doesn't work because in current Jade versions filters are not exposed the the generated mixin code.